# Why class method appears twice in the call stack of the crash log, iOS

Tags: ios, exc-bad-access, crash-reports

I got a crash log from an app that is already in App Store. The weird part of the crash log is that a class method appears twice in the backtrace of the crashed thread, as if the class method recursively called itself. I said weird because that class method is quite simple and it doesn't make a recursive call inside method body. Here is the part from the crash log:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b788350 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b6fefb2 pthread_kill + 54
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b73b366 abort + 90
3   btg2                            0x0172a358 ___lldb_unnamed_function128645$$btg2 + 280
4   btg2                            0x0171af34 ___lldb_unnamed_function128478$$btg2 + 256
5   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b708d38 _sigtramp + 40
6   btg2                            0x0129fd7c +[PHAPIRequest expectedSignatureValueForResponse:nonce:secret:] (PHAPIRequest.m:129)
7   btg2                            0x0129fd7c +[PHAPIRequest expectedSignatureValueForResponse:nonce:secret:] (PHAPIRequest.m:129)
8   btg2                            0x012a1ee4 -[PHAPIRequest connectionDidFinishLoadingWithRequest:response:data:context:] (PHAPIRequest.m:501)
9   btg2                            0x012aee04 -[PHConnectionManager connectionDidFinishLoading:] (PHConnectionManager.m:234)
10  Foundation                      0x33d46912 __65-[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:]_block_invoke_0 + 14
11  Foundation                      0x33c86764 -[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:] + 196
12  Foundation                      0x33c86680 -[NSURLConnectionInternal _withActiveConnectionAndDelegate:] + 56
13  CFNetwork                       0x330e764c ___delegate_didFinishLoading_block_invoke_0 + 24
14  CFNetwork                       0x330e6d30 ___withDelegateAsync_block_invoke_0 + 52
15  CFNetwork                       0x3310f010 ___performAsync_block_invoke_068 + 16
16  CoreFoundation                  0x33350aca CFArrayApplyFunction + 174
17  CFNetwork                       0x3310f46e RunloopBlockContext::perform() + 70
18  CFNetwork                       0x3307345e MultiplexerSource::perform() + 186
19  CoreFoundation                  0x333df8f4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 12
20  CoreFoundation                  0x333df158 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 208
21  CoreFoundation                  0x333ddf2a __CFRunLoopRun + 642
22  CoreFoundation                  0x33351238 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
23  CoreFoundation                  0x333510c4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
24  GraphicsServices                0x36f0c336 GSEventRunModal + 70
25  UIKit                           0x3526d2b4 UIApplicationMain + 1116
26  btg2                            0x0007da00 main (main.mm:21)
27  btg2                            0x0007a504 ___lldb_unnamed_function1$$btg2 + 36
```

Does any one have a reasoning why +[PHAPIRequest expectedSignatureValueForResponse:nonce:secret:] appears twice in the backtrace or may be knows the reason of the crash? Appreciate your help!

Comment: did you have any recursiv logic in the expectedSignatureValueForResponse method?

Comment: No, there is no recursive logic in the method.